# ただのリスティング運用者がグーグルから次のように言われて何をすれば良いでしょうか？

Tags: jquery

皆さま、お世話になります。また予め御礼申し上げます。

HPをリニューアル致しました。そこで[image: 下記]
のような「機能していないリンク先」つまりプログラムに機能していないリンク先が有るよ、と言われ、広告とソースが連動せず広告が表示出来ないで困っているのですが、平気でプログラムのド素人さんに難しい事を言ってくるグーグルの社員さん達の言う通りにするには何をすれば良いのでしょうか？（尚、同時並行でホームページ業者にも依頼をしています。）

グーグル社員さん曰く、HPに富んでCTR+SFT+Iキーを押せ。⇒Networksというところが有るからそこでクリックしながらF５キーを押せ。すると赤い文字が見えるのだろう。あれを修正すればいいんだよ。との事ですが、ど素人の私に何かアドバイス、ヒント、ずばりお答えでも頂けますと
幸いです。（下記F5キーを押した後の図）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: タイトルには質問の内容を簡潔に書いてください。あなたの属性の情報は不要です。

Comment: あなたが「ただの運用者/素人」なのか「HP作成のスペシャリト」なのかは、残念ながらGoogleも我々も知る由もありません。質問の件に限らず、何かに関わる以上はご自身で覚えていただくか、然るべき担当者に任せるかになるんじゃないでしょうか。スタックオーバーフローはプログラミング関連に的を絞ったQAサイトです。[過去質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/44088/3060)でもそうですが、内々の事情や愚痴に近いものが質問の前面に出ているとあまり印象がよくありません。この場にいるのもあくまで(業務上の関わりが無い)ただの素人だということをご留意ください。

Comment: 皆さま、ご迷惑をおかけして申し訳御座いません(m_m)。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F5キーを押した後の図、で 赤字になって部分ですが、ajax-loader.gif というファイルにアクセスしたけど、ファイルが見つからないよ、という意味のエラーです。

ajax-loader.gif というファイルをホームページのサーバーの 所定の場所にコピーすれば良いと思いますよ。

Comment: 有難う御座います！不評な質問にすみません(m_m)

Comment: 全然大丈夫ですよ。ただこのサイトにはガイドラインがあって、それに沿わないと、コメントが色々ついちゃうんですね。基本的はヘルプを開いていただいて、どんな質問が望まれるのか 把握なさってもらえると良いと思います。